# How do I only allow Sorting on a Filtered column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to find out how I can use the filter button to only choose sort functions, otherwise it has a ton of numerical values that are completely irrelevant to select.

All I need is to be able to sort in most columns, but not all. How can I do this?

Here's what I see-

[image: Filter with Values]

Here's what I want-

[image: Filter with Only Sort]

Notice how in the first there's a bunch of values that no one cares to see, but in the second there's only the ability to sort the data.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you maybe add a screenshot to explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Updated per your request

Comment: If you're asking to modify the filter/sort window - no that's not possible.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It's just so ugly... Thank you!